# Touchpad was disabled after plugging a Bluetooth mouse in and back out

Tags: xorg, mouse, bluetooth, touchpad, xinput

I have installed Arch Linux on my computer (Asus K53SV) and everything works well. But after I plug in my Bluetooth mouse, which is a Logitech M215, then the touchpad is disabled, except for the left and right mouse buttons. The mouse cursor doesn't move though I move my hand on touchpad.

So, what is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: external mouse is disabling touchpad. this is done by some process. what desktop environment are you using? xfce? gnome?

Comment: I use cinnamon. How can I do?